# How to invoke NdrClientCall2() function directly?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, rpc

Does anybody know how the `NdrClientCall2()` function in rpcrt4.dll can be called in code or how it can be used?

We've gone through the MSDN help - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374215(VS.85).aspx,

but didn't get any examples/samples how to use this function.

Please provide help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't ever call it directly - it requires a huge set of parameters prepared in a special barely-manageable way. Instead you use IDL to specify your RPC interface, compile it with MIDL and this gives you a client proxy that calls that function with proper parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use and idl-file and use midl.exe to generate the client RPC stub, which utilizes the NdrClientCall2 internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally called via the RPC client MIDL code - why do you want to call this directly?

Comment: Using this function directly to create services is typically found in malware.